# SSRS not connecting to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

We have our SSRS servers, on-premise. When trying to connect to the Azure SQL DB, it is throwing the following error when not using the port number 1433:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

When using the port 1433, the same error is coming only instead of Named Pipes it says TCP.
What to do? I have already added the SSRS IP to the Azure SQL DB firewall and have checked the connection string is also perfect. Since Auidting is on, we are also using 'secure' in the connection URL of the server.

Comment: Have you been able to connect from SSMS (or other programs) on the SSRS machines? Have you verified that your on-prem firewall is not denying the outbound connection?

Comment: Also one more thing to check is that outgoing IP might be different from the IP of SSRS server IP as most of enterprises funnel outgoing traffic through one or more specific IP's.